# Specify fields to return in VoyageMongo

Tags: mongodb, pharo

I am looking for a possibility to limit the return fields for a VoyageMongo Query.
Assumed I have db.persons with fields (personId, firstName, lastName).
In Mongo I can query by
`db.persons.find( { }, {'personId' : 1} )`
In VoyageMongo it seems all Dictionary entries send to the JSON Query are collated into an $and query. There is a instVar and Accessors to fields in MongoQuery, but I do not know how to set them. 
Is there a way to specify the return fields in VoyageMongo?

Regards

Max

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a while the only option I found was to extend Class, VOMongoRepository, VOMongoRepositoryResolver and MongoCollection.
I added a message chain with
`Class>>selectMany: aBlock options: someOptions
    ^self voyageRepository selectMany: self where: aBlock options: someOptions
VOMongoRepository>>selectMany: aClass where: aDictionary options: someOptions 
    | selected |
    selected := resolver selectMany: aClass where: aDictionary options: someOptions.
    ^aClass = aClass persistentClass
        ifTrue: [ selected ]
        ifFalse: [ selected select: [ :each | each isKindOf: aClass ] ]
VOMongoRepositoryResolver>>selectMany: aClass where: aDictionary options: someOptions 
    self execute: [ ^self basicSelectMany: aClass where: aDictionary options: someOptions ]
VOMongoRepositoryResolver>>basicSelectMany: aClass where: aDictionary options: someOptions
    "Selecting instances of aClass should be done in the mongo query, not here"
    self flag: #todo.
    ^((self basicRawSelectMany: aClass where: aDictionary options: someOptions)
        collect: [ :each | self retrieveObjectOf: aClass json: each ]
        as: repository collectionClass)
            select: [ :each | each isKindOf: aClass ]
VOMongoRepositoryResolver>>basicRawSelectMany: aClass where: aDictionary options: someOptions
    ^self pool withDatabase: [ :db | 
        (self collectionAt: aClass inDatabase: db) 
            select: aDictionary 
            options: someOptions ]
MongoCollection>>select: aDictionary options: someOptions
    ^ self query: [:query |
        query
            where: aDictionary;
            limit: (someOptions at: 'limit' ifAbsent: nil); 
            offset: (someOptions at: 'offset' ifAbsent: nil);
            fields: (someOptions at: 'fields' ifAbsent: nil) ]`

This solved the issue.
The message is send in that manner:

```
options := { 'fields' -> { 'personId' -> 1 } asDictionary } asDictionary.
^ self selectMany: [ :each |
    (each at: 'name') = 'Max' ]
    options: options
```

One can also add limit and offset into the options directory.
As I have objects with many fields, the performance when fetching only a few of them has changed from 48000 ms to 229 ms
I have created a package with the extension.